How to import a Utils.js file to Vue Repl?
Vue Repl repo: https://github.com/vuejs/repl
Is anyone familiar with this module? I want to import a local Utils.js file that contains a few methods to be used in the example, AppVue. Is there a documentation for this module beside the README?
Utils.js:
export const doSomething = () => {}

AppVue.text:
<script setup> 
import * as Utils from './Utils.js' 
Utils.doSomething('Hi');
</script>

Repl.vue:
<script>
const store = new useStore({})

store.setFiles({
  ...store.getFiles(),
  'App.vue': readFileAsStr('./AppVue.text'),
})

// Todo: add Utils.js file 
</script>

<template>
  <Repl :editor="CodeMirror" :store="store" />
</template>


Can you clarify what is the problem? You likely need to add Utils.js the same way as App.vue to repl project. It's used in https://github.com/vuejs/core/tree/main/packages/sfc-playground . No docs, it's for the designated use

Yes. We can add Util.js as we do with App.vue. However, it will show up as a tab in the Repl.
I want to do something similar how they did it in the Pinia library playground - https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/blob/165efa84dd9245fc34ca4d244b9f6626ca2bddd4/packages/online-playground/src/App.vue#L70
However, the ReplStore.setImportMap() method is not available in "@vue/repl": "^4.2.1" version.

Yes, that's what's needed in case this is how you want it to work. See https://github.com/vuejs/repl/commit/c8887d6e5b04f41a4a90c255d563a011ab16a60e and https://github.com/vuejs/repl#advanced-usage . A similar thing in 4 would likely be const { importMap } = useVueImportMap(); const store = useStore({ builtinImportMap: mergeImportMap(importMap, { imports: {...} }) }). Also check store's implementation, it supports import-map.json that seems to serve the same purpose
